# Change class of anchor tag using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have some issue in changing the class of an anchor tag. I have defined a hyper link which has data-target attribute. I want to change the class of this hyper link using angularjs. Like if data-target='#upen' then it should first select the element using querySelector and then change the class of hyperlink.Like we change the class of an element using id or class in this way

```
var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '.upen' ) );
myE1.addClass('.demo');
```

This will first select the element which has class upen and then change the class of that particular element. Sam thing i want for hyperlink. First it should select the anchor tag using data-target attribute like it select using class or id and then change the class of that particular hyper link.

Comment: Why don't you simply specify the class directly in the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have got the idea how to do it. It is very simple.

```
var myE4 = angular.element( document.querySelector( 'a[data-target="#upen"]' ) );
myE3.addClass('demo');
```

And it wil change the class of hyper link which has data-target="#upen".